# How to turn into a product of $2$ factors the expression : $ x^4 -3x^2+1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, soft-question

Source : Lebossé & Hémery, *Algèbre et Analyse* ( Classe de seconde , 1965).

The exercice requires  : turn into  a product of $2$ factors the expression $ x^4 -3 x^2 +1$.

The only way I see is to use the property : $P(x)$ being a polynomial , if $P(a) =0$ then $P(x)$ is divisible by $(x-a)$.

Using the  substitution $X = x^2$, the expression can be turned into : $X^2 -3X +1$

Setting $X^2 -3X +1= 0$ yields $ X = \frac {3+\sqrt5} {2}$ or $ X = \frac {3-\sqrt5} {2}$.

This implies that : $x= \pm\sqrt{ \frac {3+\sqrt5} {2}}$ or $x= \pm\sqrt{ \frac {3-\sqrt5} {2}}$.

Finally, using the property referred to above, one gets :

$ x^4 -3 x^2 +1 = ( x- \sqrt{\frac {3+\sqrt5} {2}}) ( x+ \sqrt{\frac {3+\sqrt5} {2} })( x - \sqrt{\frac {3-\sqrt5} {2}})(x+ \sqrt{\frac {3-\sqrt5} {2}})$.

But this method yields 4 factors instead of 2.

Is there a better way to meet the requirement of the exercise?

Is there a classical identity hidden below the original expression?

Comment: Decomposing into 4 factors is better than decomposing into 2 factors, to get 2, just multiply three of them together or multiply two pairs together.

Comment: You could also notice that $\,\sqrt{(3+\sqrt{5})/2}=(1+\sqrt{5})/2\,$ then regroup the terms in pairs to get rid of the radicals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is quite easy question. You said two factors.

> $$x^4-3x^2+1=(x^4-2x^2+1)-x^2=(x^2-1)^2-x^2=(x^2+x-1)(x^2-x-1).$$

Is it your answer?

Comment: Is there a classical identity corresponding to going from $(x^2-1)^2-x$ to your final expression?

Comment: Oh god I missed $^2$...

Answer (score 3):

You can stop earlier:
$$
x^4 - 3x^2 + 1
= X^2 - 3X + 1
= (X - \frac{3+\sqrt5}{2})(X - \frac{3-\sqrt5}{2})
= (x^2 - \frac{3+\sqrt5}{2})(x^2 - \frac{3-\sqrt5}{2}).
$$